# Outputting lists as variable name in for loop in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, naming

I have a loop over a function

```
months18 <- list("MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC")
for (i in months18)
{
  i <- make_list18(i)
}
```

I would like it to output 8 separate lists, each named for the month. Right now it spits out only one list called i, which has the data from the last iteration ("DEC").
I have tried
`paste(i) <- make_list18(i)` which names the i object "MAY",
and `sprintf(%s, i) <- make_list18(i)`, which does not run.
How can I change the loop to work how I want it to?

Comment: What is `make_list18`. If you need to assign to objects `assign(i, make_list18(i))` or as a named list `lst(months18) %>% map(make_list18)`

Comment: You should create a list to store the output and assign to a new piece of the `output` list in each iteration, e.g., `output <- list()` before the loop, and `output[[i]] <- make_liist18(i)` inside the loop. If you need more help than that, you probably need to make a reproducible example. (As Akrun says, we don't have `make_list18` so can't run your code or really see what's going on.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gregor Thomas for your solution. It runs now like this

```
months18 <- list("MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC")
tmp18 <- list()
for (i in months18)
{
  tmp18[[i]] <- make_list18(i)
}
```

and returns a large list

Comment: does `setNames(lapply(months18,make_list18),months18)` not work?